# Easy Way To Add Huge Amount of predefined strings to Spinner widget?

Tags: java, android, xml

is there a way to make inputting this text 
Alfa Romeo
Aston Martin
Audi
Bentley
Benz
BMW
Bugatti
Cadillac
Chevrolet
Chrysler
Citroen
Corvette
DAF
Dacia
Daewoo
Daihatsu
Datsun
De Lorean
Dino
Dodge
Farboud
Ferrari
Fiat
Ford
Honda
Hummer
Hyundai
Jaguar
Jeep
KIA
Koenigsegg
Lada
Lamborghini
Lancia
Land Rover
Lexus
Ligier
... All the car companies;

into the strings.xml easily/fast...for example i dont want to write `<item></item>` around each car make individually.

or do i?....

Any help much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can keep a text file in the raw folder with comma(,) separated values and read them in onCreate of any activity:

```
 private List<String> mFileItems;
```

and then

```
int textFile = R.raw.keywords;
mFileItems = Arrays.asList(Utils.getStringFromRaw(this, textFile).replace("\"", "").split("\\s*,\\s*"));
```

and

```
public class Utils {


public static String getStringFromRaw(Context mContext, int resource) throws IOException {
    Resources r = mContext.getResources();
    InputStream is = r.openRawResource(resource);
    String statesText = convertStreamToString(is);
    is.close();
    return statesText;
}

private static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    int i = is.read();
    while (i != -1) {
        byteArrayOutputStream.write(i);
        i = is.read();
    }
    return byteArrayOutputStream.toString();
}
}
```

This will compile you a list of all the items in the list which are comma separated. Then you can set it in the spinner adapter.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you please mark the answer as right if you find it correct?

Comment: Is there not an easier way? im trying to pre define these within the strings.xml and when i go to pre define them with <item> </item> how can i do it very quickly instead like last night i just copied <item> and pasted it around each one... in the strings.xml is therte a technique to make putting <> xml tags around the strings faster? is me putting the pre defined strings in the striongs.xml bad or performance decreasing?

Comment: No its not a bad performance. The method i suggested is easy because you can always edit a text file more easily than a strings file. You just have to put the values in the text file comma separated and the script will do the rest. I would say as both the files are inside your project, the performance would be almost same.